# cvSetMouseCallback - Which window does events come from?

Tags: c++, opencv

I created many windows by using `imshow` and i am using the `cvSetMouseCallback` function in order to get mouse position and the currently pressed buttons.

But i couldn't understand which window an event comes from? How can I know what window generates what event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `param` parameter on the `cvSetMouseCallback` function to pass a user-defined parameter to your mouse callback. Then, in your callback you can read that parameter to determine what window the mouse event came from.

Here is the definition of the [`cvSetMouseCallback`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=cvsetmousecallback#void%20cvSetMouseCallback%28const%20char*%20window_name,%20CvMouseCallback%20on_mouse,%20void*%20param%29) function:

```
void cvSetMouseCallback(const char* window_name, CvMouseCallback on_mouse, void* param=NULL )
```

You can use the third parameter to pass a pointer to anything you like (for example, the name of the window). Here is an example:

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        const char* winname = (const char*)param;
        cout << "Mouse button down on window " << winname << endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow("win1");
    cvNamedWindow("win2");
    cvSetMouseCallback("win1", on_mouse, "win1");
    cvSetMouseCallback("win2", on_mouse, "win2");
    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

This app will write the window name in the console when you click on any of the two windows. Here is how it looks like:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: thank you very much Ove. i fixed the problem as you said